How does a steel ball's weight vary at different water depths?
A steel ball becomes lighter when immersed in water - its mass is the same but its measured weight is less. So, does the steel ball weigh less, at a water depth of one kilometre, than the same ball a few centimetres below the water's surface?
And, in space, as gravity is neutral, does this buoyancy force disappear?

As for your last question, it does unless your in a noninertial (i.e. an accelerating) frame a la the equivalence principle.

I'm not sure what you mean by gravity being neutral in space, gravity doesn't just stop when you exit earths atmosphere. Otherwise the moon wouldn't be orbiting the earth nor the earth orbiting the sun.

Do we have to account for the reduction of $g$ as we go to depth?

Short answer: yes, the ball will feel slightly lighter at 1 km depth than at a shallower depth.  Water is slightly compressible, so at a depth of 1 km it will be slightly denser, and will exert more buoyant force on the ball.

It depends on your definition of weight. If it's gravitational weight defined by $\vec W=m\vec g$, then NO this type of weight does not change no matter how deep you put the ball under water.
If it's operational weight - force with which body affects its support - then YES, it does depend on net force affecting body. In this case operational weight is defined as $\vec W = m\vec g - \rho_fV_{disp}~\vec g$. So if you attach weighing scales like this:

then they will measure smaller body weight than compared measuring in the air. BTW, this effect can be used to measure human body composition (average density), since fat has slightly smaller density, $\approx 0.9~kg/L$ than water in human cells ($1~kg/L$).

(+1) If the cube is lifted into the air above the water, then the air is still a fluid that provides some buoyancy (though not as much as water), so then the cube should weight slightly less in air, compared to in pure vacuum?

@James yes, about 1 gram per litre (it's practically equal to the density of air)

thank you. Will the block that is submerged in water make it easier for us to push it forward (horizontal movement)?

@James The inertia of an object to be be moved horizontally depends on its mass (as measured far out in space) and not on its weight, so it would not be easier to move the object sideways. In fact it will be more difficult due to the viscous friction of the water. Ever tried running in waist deep water?

@KDP thank you. Could one say the viscosity is always discounting the force applied in any direction? If the applied force is downward (gravity), viscosity discounts this force making it appear to have smaller apparent weight. If the applied force is sideways, viscosity discounts this too the same way making it harder to accelerate the object?

@James The friction force due to viscosity resists motion in any direction but does not prevent it. If the object is stationary the viscous friction force is zero and has nothing to do with the apparent reduced weight due to buoyancy.

@KDP thank you. Suppose the ball is moving fast in the water. Does the ball's own movement cause the viscosity of the water immediately surrounding it to increase?

I'm not going to worry about the points made about definitions in prior answers...though to say something that floats, like The Titanic (err, floated), or a The Seawise Giant supertanker are "weightless" is...odd.
So:
"Is there more buoyant force deeper in the ocean?"
We generally do physics problems with water being an incompressible fluid, but after that mini-sub thingy got smooshed, I learned that just the expansion of the water going from 300 atm to 1 atm was bad enough.
The web says the surface density of seawater is 1.020 - 1.029 (vs. regular water). Now you have salinity and temperature gradients to worry about (water is most dense at 4C (iirc)), but we're talking pressure effects here, and it can reach 1.050 [I can't give a reference since it appears AI generated that on the spot].
So: yes, it's more buoyant at depth.

at depth, iron gets compressed as well. Water probably compresses better, but not sure about this point

@fraxinus water's about 80x more compressible than iron (comparing bulk moduli), although it varies a lot more with temperature and pressure for water

Let us divide the world into 3 parts and consider various combinations of those parts.

The steel ball
The ocean around the ball
The ball of water that would be there if the steel ball was not

If you have just a steel ball, gravity pulls it down. This is the weight of the ball. The ball would fall.
If you have just the ball of water, it would fall. The weight of the ball is less than the weight of the steel ball because steel is denser than water.
If you have the ball of water and the ocean around it, you have the ocean. No part of the ocean falls. The total force on any part of the ocean is $0$. This means the force the ocean exerts on the ball is upward and just strong enough to balance the weight of the ball of water.
This force comes from the weight of the water above. It makes the ocean press into any hole and fill in the hole. This is the pressure the ocean exerts on a submerged object. The object must exert an equal pressure outward to keep from being crushed.
Where the surface of the rest of the ocean presses on the ball of water, there is a force. The force at the bottom of the ball is bigger than the force at the top. This is why the net force is upward.
If you replace the ball of water with the ball of steel, the rest of the ocean exerts the same force. The upward force on the steel ball is the same as the weight of a ball of water. This is less than the weight of the steel ball. It isn't enough to hold the steel ball up, so the steel ball sinks.
None of this changes if the steel ball is near the surface or near the bottom of the ocean.
What does change is the pressure. The pressure at the bottom of the ocean is immense. But it is a little less at the top of the sphere than the bottom. The net upward force on the sphere is the same as the weight of a ball of water.
If you have a ball in water in space, gravity does not pull the water down. No pressure is exerted. The water and the ball just float with no forces on them.

But water is slightly compressible.  So at extreme depths, with denser water, I believe there will be significantly greater buoyant force.

The “weight” of an object is generally defined as the force of gravity on an object, though Wikipedia does state “there is some variation and debate as to the exact definition”.
To say a steel ball becomes “lighter” when immersed in water is generally referred to as the “apparent” weight of the steel ball caused by the upward buoyant force exerted on the ball. That force equals the weight of the volume of water displaced by the ball (Archimedes Principle).
Hope this helps.
